# List<MyClass*> & array question

Tags: c++, arrays, list, pointers

Assuming a definition like this,

```
void CConfigTest::OnSelchangedTree(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    NM_TREEVIEW* pNMTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;
    TVITEM item = pNMTreeView->itemNew;
    // find the session of the selected item
    if(item.hItem != NULL)
    {
        HTREEITEM root, parent, node;
        node = item.hItem;
        parent = m_treeSM.GetParentItem(item.hItem);
        root = m_treeSM.GetRootItem();

        while(parent != root && parent != NULL)
        {
            node = parent;
            parent = m_treeSM.GetParentItem(parent); 
        }

        MyCommand* pCmd = (MyCommand*)(m_treeSM.GetItemData(node));
                ....
                ....
```

I tried these statements below, but failed.

```
pCmd->subList[2]
(pCmd->subList)[2]
```

How can I get the array member values(such as subList[2]). I want to replace the value of subList[2] with other same type value. Thank you.

Comment: the code sample seems to be an error.
m_treeSM.GetItemData does not seem to be linked to subList in any way.

Comment: also, pCmd will not have subList as a member.
So pCmd->subList will fail.

Comment: It's a snippet code only. Actually there is a **load file** behavior to load a complete file to memory. It works quite well. :-)

Comment: you need to provide a better snippet then. the other commenters are right with their vector remarks.

Comment: I update them. OnSelchangedTree() is a Control function when select different node after load the file. And I just want to modify the sub node item(array item) value dynamically and apply the update value to another CWin Obj for using. That won't cause I modify the original file.

Comment: what is the signature/prototype for GetItemData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists do not support random access.  You need to switch to another container type which does, or iterate over the list until you reach the element you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to array like behavior and use the subscript operator you should use `std::vector` and not `std::list`. Then you can use it just like an array for accessing and replacing elements.